# Почему не передается значение, которое вписываешь в textField?

Tags: swift

Имеется следующая функция, которая по нажатии на кнопку высвечивает окошко, куда пользователь вписывает свое число:

```
    @objc func addRowToEnd() {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add new income / expense", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { [self] (textField) in
        if let mText = textField.text {
            new_income_expense = Float(mText) ?? 100.0
        }
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Update",
            style: .default,
            handler: { [self](updateAction) in
            self.cellArr.append("\(new_income_expense)") // Добавление в массив нового элемента
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.cellArr.count - 1,
                section: 0)],
                with: .automatic) // + 1 элемент
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: false) // Высвечивает окошко
        
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        
        balanceScore = self.balanceScore + new_income_expense
        self.balance.text = "Your Balance: \(balanceScore)"
    }
```

Проблема в том, что вместо моего числа, которое я вписываю, в таблицу все равно вставляется значение 100 по умолчанию, будто мое вписанное игнорируется, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эта строка new_income_expense = Float(mText) ?? 100.0 означает, что если  преобразование Float возвращает nil, то будет подставляться 100. То есть Float не может превратить mText в число. Возможно, mText это набор букв и т.п.